# Command to change package name in Grails

Tags: grails

I have created my application under package music. Now I want to change my package to com.mp3.songs.music.

One way is I can manually create the package for grails-app. Is there anything else that I need to take care while changing the package name.

Alternatively, is there a command in grails which can be used to change the package.

I found a way out in the below link. But this works only when you create new files. What if you want to change the package of the older files.

http://www.goto20.nl/tech/groovy/configuring-the-default-package-name-for-a-grails-project/

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not use Spring Source Tool Suite. Its a great IDE with solid support for Groovy n Grails.

Comment: I am using STS. My project is complete and now there is a request for a package change. Using STS, I can create a new package for ctrllers, domain etc. Instead of doing that manually, is there any configuration that can be mentioned or probably a command that can be run, that changes the package change across.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the package name in STS? Select the package, press F2 and change the name. That's it and it re factors the name across the project. I hope that's what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ Jay :Exactly what I am trying to achieve Jay. But, using F2 or by refactoring, the changes dont get refactored across the project. You have to manually do F2 on controller package, domain, test/unit, test/integration and services. I believe there should be some method/Command/ that does the changes throughout.

Comment: Oh ok. Now I got it. I am not aware of a single command that does that. Since each are in different packages in itself, I guess you have to do F2 for each i.e. controller package, domain package etc.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA has very good support for rename refactoring. I believe it is currently the best (9.0.3 stable) chance you'll have of any major refactoring jobs in Grails. They have a 30 day trial, so it is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks Vaskin. Unfortunately I do not have IntelliJ IDEA. :(

Comment: I actually just had to do this in IntelliJ 12 and it wasn't very pleasant :/

Comment: In IntelliJ 2018 community edition (free) it is extremely easy, you just right click on the main package (eg. in services), then Refactor -> Move... and the IDE performs this change in controllers, tests, everywhere.